# Image gallery item counting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, count, gallery

I'm trying to create a simple image gallery, using data stored in a json object. It works perfectly, except I cant seem to successfully 'reset' the image count after closing the image, and each time I open the image the ordering is wrong. I know it's to do with modulo, but I cant figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
$.getJSON('js/work.json', function(data){

  var current = 0;
  var projects = data.projects;
  var currArr;

  $('.work-row > div').on('click', function(){

    current = 0;

    var i = $(this).index('.work-row div');
    currArr = projects[i];

    preloadImages(currArr, function(){


      $('.pop-forward').click(function(){
        current ++;
        current = current % currArr.images.length;
        $('.pop').css('backgroundImage', 'url(../images/work/main/'+currArr.dir+'/'+currArr.images[current].src+'.jpg)');
      });


      $('.pop-back').click(function(){
        current--;
        current = (current < 0) ? currArr.images.length-1 : current;
        $('.pop').css('backgroundImage', 'url(../images/work/main/'+currArr.dir+'/'+currArr.images[current].src+'.jpg)');
      });


      $('.close-image').click(function(){
        current = 0;
      });

    });

  });
```

And here's the json:

```
{
  "projects": [
      {
          "dir" : "project1",
          "copy" : "Lorem Ipsum",
          "images" : [
          { 
           "src": "image1"
          },
          { 
           "src": "image2"
          },
          { 
           "src": "image3"
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: the modulo operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another. You do not need this mathematical operation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
current = current % currArr.images.length;
```

should be

```
current = current >= currArr.images.length ? 0 : current;
```

This should fix the ordering problems.

Put your global `current` var before the first function.